# Covering map of a sheet to an open set of the base space -- why is onto included in the definition?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the definition of a covering map (in Lee: Topological Manifolds, and Munkres Topology) why does the definition say that the covering map of a given sheet must be onto an open set in the base space, when it is already given that the restriction of a covering map to a sheet must be a homeomorphism.  Could there be a homeomorphism of one open set to another which is not onto?  Seems like overkill to me

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $p: D^2 \to D^2$ (where $D^2$ is the closed unit disk) given by $p(x, y) = (x/2, y/2)$. Then $p$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, but the image is not an open set in the base space.

By the way, there is no requirement that the restriction of the covering map to a sheet be a homeomorphism. The requirement is merely that it be a local homeomorphism. If you think about the map $S^1 \to S^1: \theta \mapsto 2\theta$, then the notion of "a sheet" of the cover can only be defined locally anyhow!

Comment: John Hughes Thanks -- I was hung up on the (fact?) that all homeomorphisms are onto their image, rather than the stimulation that the image must be an open set.

Comment: stipulation rather than stimulation

Comment: @JohnHughes I think typically a sheet is defined (locally) so that the restriction to it is a homeomorphism. In the standard definiton around any point there is some neighborhood where the map is a homeomorphism.  This neighborhood is what I think is called a sheet. I still don't get what is gained by not assuming covering maps are globally surjective and find it strange whenever some source doesn't make that assumption.

Comment: I agree; I was pointing out the inaccuracy/sloppiness in something that OP wrote. As for surjectivity (at the global scale), I agree completely.

Comment: Lee and Munkres both assume that covering maps are surjective.  Lee defines a sheet as one of the connected open subsets of the covering space found by taking the preimage of an open set in the base space.

Comment: My point is that a sheet is one of the connected open subsets of the covering space found by taking the preimage of a *small enough, connected open set* in the base; otherwise in the standard double-cover of the circle by a circle, the covering circle would be a "sheet", since it's the preimage of a connected open subset of the base (namely, the preimage of the WHOLE base).

Comment: I had trouble with this as well.  If you look at Lee's definition of covering map (p. 278), he says that every point x of the base space X, has an evenly covered neighborhood (open set containing x).  He does NOT say that this is true for every open set containing x (such as the whole space).